# validate requests with swagger and lambda

Tags: node.js, swagger, aws-lambda

We are using aws gateway api with lambda functions to create our api.
We then decided that it would be a good idea to have it all documented with swagger, and use it to validate the requests in a similar fashion as it happens with express middleware frameworks.

However i cant find a way to pass a request object and validate it against a swagger spec manually without using one of these frameworks.

Now my question is:

- How do validate a request against a swagger spec, by pointing the request at a specific path in spec, what frameworks could i use to achieve it?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find out how to do this? Thanks

Comment: No not yet, i end up giving up on it, i am doing another service i will probably try again in a couple weeks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would be interested to know the answer if you figure it out as I'm looking to do the same thing.